# Box-sizing no input button não funciona

Tags: html, css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pessoal, tenho um formulário no qual quando aplico um border-bottom no input button  ele dá um pulo devido ao box-sizing não está funcionando (acredito que seja isso). Nos demais input está funcionando corretamente. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma dica, use `box-shadow` no lugar do `border`. Primeiro pq o `box-shadow` não ocupa luar no box-model e não vai deslocar ou mover seu elemento, depois que a transição do `box-shadow` costuma ser melhor renderizada e é mais suave do que a transição com bordas. Então fazendo um `box-shadow: inset` vc coloca a sombra para dentro do botão, dando a impressão que é uma borda.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
[type="button"] {
 all:unset;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, blue 0%, royalblue 100%);
 color: #fff;
 width: 100px;
 height: 50px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 text-align: center;
  cursor:pointer;
 transition: box-shadow 250ms;
}
[type="button"]:hover {
 box-shadow: inset 0 -4px 0 red;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="login">
```

Comment: Obrigado! Nem conhecia essa propriedade

Comment: @RenanVilela essa propriedade é muito útil depois tire um tempo para estuda-la. Se vc achar que a resposta resolve o problema lembre-se de marca-la como aceita nesse ícone abaixo das setinha ✔, depois se aparecer outra resposta que vc ache mais apropriada vc pode mudar a ✔ para ela